# How to view plugin ratings?

Tags: plugin-development

So I recently submitted my first plugin, and have since got a 1-star rating. Is there a place to review ratings and comments on my plugin?

Comment: Tried the stats tab?

Comment: just gives me a number of downloads...nothing on ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to see the individual ratings, but you can see the total number of ratings and what they average out to. In the bottom left of your plugin page (in the repository) there is a section for "What others are saying", and it will display any posts from the WordPress forum talking about your plugin.

Comment: Is this your plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/op-archive/ ? if so, one thing that you could definitely do to improve it (purely on the presentation front) is to write out a much more detailed description, include screenshots, and just explain more about how the plugin works, how people use it, etc.

Comment: Pippin, thanks for the words of advice. I'll be updating the description and adding much more functionality. I only uploaded it to the repository so soon to get a feel for how the process works to publish plugins.